# Get Chrome to Download DWG Files

Tags: html, google-chrome

Is there some reason why Google Chrome will not allow a DWG file to download?

```
<a id="original_link" target="_blank"
  download="LGV-00002-2.dwg"
  style="display: inline-block;"
  href="\\FileShare01\share\Engineering\Drawings\LGV-00002-2.dwg">
LGV-00002-2.dwg</a>
```

I've done some searching, and it appears there are several plugins to view a DWG file in the Chrome browser, but we have no way of knowing which of our employees have installed such a plugin.

We'd just like it to download.

Currently, you click the link and nothing happens. The file downloads successfully in Internet Explorer.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: My thinking is that your back-slashes in the `a href` should be forward slashes (`/`).

Comment: If that is the reason: Why is Chrome changing the slashes, and how do I stop that on other's browsers? As you can see from the sample code I posted and the URL that Chrome shows in the Status Bar, the slashes are written one way and interpreted by Chrome the other way.